# Center UIButton and UILabel with Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I'm a newbie when it comes to `UIConstraints` and i'm trying to center the "Continue Button" and "No, thanks" with `Auto Layout` in the space between the `UICollectionView` and the bottom in the `xib`. Which `UIConstraints` should i add?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered `UIStackView`?

Comment: @PetahChristian first time i'm reading about it.

Comment: @bruno I would highly recommend you consider using `UIStackView` for laying out your view. Here's a tutorial re: how to do it that I found helpful. http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views. Here's a video from WWDC 2015 covering it, as well. At around the 5:15 second mark is the part that's relevant--> https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-218/.

Comment: @PetahChristian after implementing 4 UIStackView i multiple constraints i got the job done, thanks ;)

Comment: Nice! You should post your solution as an answer to your own question, to help others out in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the implementation i made

[image]

As you can see in the image, i implemented 3 Stack Views with the different components. To make them all "one" i put them in a Stack with constraints <= to the bottom and top and constraints with a fixed size so that they don't go pass the bounds of the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use absolute values, you need two more transparent views to obtain the layout you want.

One view, should be added above "Continue" and it should have it's top margin set to the `collectionView` and the bottom margin set to "Continue".
The second view should be placed under "No thanks" and it should have the top margin set to "No thanks" and the bottom margin set to the bottom of the superView.
You can have both views take up all the horizontal space by adding left and right margins equal to the superView.

After you set the constraints I mentioned above, you have to add one more equal height constraint between the two extra views. This will ensure that the space above "Continue" and under "No thanks" will always be equal.

Comment: That sounds a bit messy

Comment: @bruno it's one of the things that auto-layout doesn't have an elegant solution for

Comment: @bruno: It is a nice solution.

Comment: This is no longer true for iOS 9.  You now can use `UILayoutGuide` in place of spacer views.